# Angular2: How to write update query for multiple existing data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, angular, angular2-template

I have updated data coming from client for updating existing data
Here what i did:

```
server.post('/edit', function(req, res){
var i = req.body;
todo.findOne({"_id" : i._id}, function(err, data){
   console.log('inside findone function');
   if(err){
       console.log('error')
   }else{
       console.log(data);

 todo.update({"taskobj" : "i.taskobj"},
{"taskdetail":"i.taskdetail"}, {multi :true}, function(err, data){
           console.log('inside update');
           if(err){
               console.log('error')
           }else{

               console.log('inside else of update');
               console.log(data);
           }
```

Its not getting into update, schema has only task and taskdetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
todo.update({"taskobj" : "i.taskobj"},
```

selector tells to update all documents in `todo` collection, which have `taskobj` property equal to `"i.taskobj"`. It is more likely you wanted to write your selector like

```
todo.update({"taskobj" : i.taskobj},
```

to update all documents in `todo` collection, which have `taskobj` property equal to value of `taskobj` property of `i`